# Prevent Kubernetes from restarting container when I shut down PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, database-replication, postgresql-9.6

I'm maintaining a Kubernetes cluster which includes two PostgreSQL servers in two different pods, a primary and a replica.  The replica is sync'ed from the primary via log shipping.

A glitch caused the log shipping to start failing so the replica is no longer in sync with the primary.

The process for bringing a replica back into sync with the primary requires, amongst other things, stopping the postgres service of the replica.  And this is where I'm having trouble.

It appears that Kubernetes is restarting the container as soon as I shut down the postgres service, which immediately restarts postgres again.  I need the container running with the postgres service inside it stopped, to allow me to perform the next steps in fixing the broken replication.

How can I get Kubernetes to allow me to shut down the postgres service without restarting the container?

**Further Details:**

To stop the replica I run a shell on the replica pod via `kubectl exec -it <pod name> -- /bin/sh`, then run `pg_ctl stop` from the shell.  I get the following response:

```
server shutting down
command terminated with exit code 137
```

and I'm kicked out of the shell.

When I run `kubectl describe pod` I see the following:

```
Name:         pgset-primary-1
Namespace:    qa
Priority:     0
Node:         aks-nodepool1-95718424-0/10.240.0.4
Start Time:   Fri, 09 Jul 2021 13:48:06 +1200
Labels:       app=pgset-primary
              controller-revision-hash=pgset-primary-6d7d65c8c7
              name=pgset-replica
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=pgset-primary-1
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.42
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.42
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/pgset-primary
Containers:
  pgset-primary:
    Container ID:   containerd://bc00b4904ab683d9495ad020328b5033ecb00d19c9e5b12d22de18f828918455
    Image:          *****/crunchy-postgres:centos7-9.6.8-1.6.0
    Image ID:       docker.io/*****/crunchy-postgres@sha256:2850e00f9a619ff4bb6ff889df9bcb2529524ca8110607e4a7d9e36d00879057
    Port:           5432/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 06 Nov 2021 18:29:34 +1300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 06 Nov 2021 18:28:09 +1300
      Finished:     Sat, 06 Nov 2021 18:29:18 +1300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  6
    Limits:
      cpu:     250m
      memory:  512Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     10m
      memory:  256Mi
    Environment:
      PGHOST:                 /tmp
      PG_PRIMARY_USER:        primaryuser
      PG_MODE:                set
      PG_PRIMARY_HOST:        pgset-primary
      PG_REPLICA_HOST:        pgset-replica
      PG_PRIMARY_PORT:        5432
      [...]
      ARCHIVE_TIMEOUT:        60
      MAX_WAL_KEEP_SEGMENTS:  400
    Mounts:
      /backrestrepo from backrestrepo (rw)
      /pgconf from pgbackrestconf (rw)
      /pgdata from pgdata (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from pgset-sa-token-nh6ng (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  pgdata:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pgdata-pgset-primary-1
    ReadOnly:   false
  backrestrepo:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  backrestrepo-pgset-primary-1
    ReadOnly:   false
  pgbackrestconf:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      pgbackrest-configmap
    Optional:  false
  pgset-sa-token-nh6ng:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  pgset-sa-token-nh6ng
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                 From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  88m (x3 over 3h1m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulled   88m (x7 over 120d)  kubelet  Container image "*****/crunchy-postgres:centos7-9.6.8-1.6.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created  88m (x7 over 120d)  kubelet  Created container pgset-primary
  Normal   Started  88m (x7 over 120d)  kubelet  Started container pgset-primary
```

The events suggest the container was started by Kubernetes.

The pod has no liveness or readiness probes so I don't know what would prompt Kubernetes to restart the container when I shut down the postgres service running within it.

Comment: You could try scaling the StatefulSet down to zero, then mounting the PersistentVolumeClaim into a new pod to repair it.  Asking this question on another site like [Database Administrators SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com) might get a better response; Stack Overflow is generally about programming questions and not cluster or database administration.

Comment: In the end I got advice from a Kubernetes engineer.  He said the container is just a wrapper around the postgres service, so stopping the service stops the container, then Kubernetes restarts it.  He advised to use a different approach to fixing replication: Since we are using crunchy postgres we should: 1) Delete the postgresql.conf file from the replica; 2) Delete the replica pod (deleting the pod doesn't delete the conf file, since we're using persistent volumes).  This recreates the replica as a copy of the primary database, and log shipping will restart automatically.  It worked.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to [restartPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy). Container lifecycle is terminated due to its process being completed. If you do not want a new container to be created you need to change the restart policy for these pods.

If this pod is a part of deployment, look into `kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy`

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately the database pods don't seem to be part of a deployment.